# How to pass a SplitContainer and the Panel object to a method

Tags: c#, methods, treeview, parameter-passing

I would like to send a SplitContainer object and one of it's Panel objects to a method where I  have statements to add a ListView to the Panel. Many Forms will use the method so it needs to be generic.

```
CustomerSplitContainer1.Panel2
```

is what I want to send but all I can send is the parent.

```
Method(CustomerSplitContainer1);

Method(SplitContainer sc)
{

various statements;
sc.Panel2.Controls.Add(myTreeView);

}
```

How do I send both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `SplitContainer.Panel2` is of type `SplitterPanel`, you can just make a method that accepts that as a parameter.

```
void methodName(SplitterPanel panel)
{
   ....
}
```

Then you can call it with `methodName(CustomSplitContainer1.Panel2)`.